# How to make display and editor for merged field in ContentPart view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I have created a `ContentPart` in a module and in `Migration` i used `.WithField` method to add an `EnumerationField` into my `ContentPart`:

```
contentPartDefinitionBuilder.WithField(
                "DealType",
                fieldBuilder =>
                {
                    fieldBuilder.OfType(typeof(EnumerationField).Name);
                    fieldBuilder.WithSetting("Options", "Op1" + Environment.NewLine +
                                                        "Op2" );
                    fieldBuilder.WithSetting("ListMode", "Radiobutton");
                });
```

My question is that how to create display in `Views/MyPart_Display.cshtml` file and also editor in `Views/MyPart_Edit.cshtml` file for `DealType` field?

**Edit:** Exactly what i want is just a method like `Html.EditorFor(m = > m.DealType)` that produces the default editor (Enumeration) for DealType field. and by this way i can wrap it by custom wapper `<div class="dealtype-field-wrapper" />`. also if we could do this by `Placement.info` mechanism it could solve my problem.Of course i know we can warp any `ContentPart` by placement:

```
<Match ContentType="Widget">
    <Place Parts_Common_Body="Content:5;Wrapper=Wrapper_DealTypeContent" />
</Match>
```

But after searching much i didn't find solution for wrapping field.

Comment: What is not working for you with the default editor?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Just override the default templates from your module?

Comment: I have edited my question. please check.